# Where does chrome.Storage save?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I can't find the location on OSX or Windows.

I can't figure out where chrome.storage.local.set saves.  It doesn't show even show any saved data under Inspect Element -> Resources.

Answer (score 2):

It gets stored inside your local chrome profile. I.e. on linux somewhere like ~/.profiles/GoogleChrome and Application Data in windows.

But it sounds like you are just wanting to inspect what's in chrome.storage.local. To do this, simply call:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(function(d){console.log(d)})
```

If you read the docs it says if you call get with only one parameter, the callback, then it returns all the contents.

I agree it would be cool if the inspector showed the contents of chrome.storage.local.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Resources tab doesn't show this in Dev Tools, but I use an extension called Storage Area Explorer Beta that's in the Chrome Web Store, and it shows local storage.